# How to iterate through elements of the first column of a text file using bash?

Tags: bash, for-loop, variables

I'm trying to grab each element in the first column of a text file using bash.

How can I read each element in as a variable?

```
for ID_SAMPLE in cut -f1 manifest.tsv
do
echo $ID_SAMPLE
done


$ bash test.sh
cut
-f1
manifest.tsv
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for ID_SAMPLE in $(cut -f1 manifest.tsv)
do
 echo $ID_SAMPLE
done
```

or backticks:

```
for ID_SAMPLE in `cut -f1 manifest.tsv`; do echo $ID_SAMPLE; done
```

Comment: AHHH I was so close I forgot the $ before the paranthesis on my other tries.